# Custom navigation controller works in iOS 13 but not in iOS 12

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, initialization

I have created a custom `UINavigationController` as follows-

```swift
class NavigationViewController: UINavigationController {
    override init(rootViewController: UIViewController) {
        super.init(rootViewController: rootViewController)
        setup()
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        return nil
    }
    func setup() {
    }
}
```

I am using the above navigation controller as follows-

```swift
let viewController = NavigationViewController(rootViewController: UIViewController())
present(viewController, animated: true)
```

The above code works as expected in iOS 13 but fails with following error in iOS 12

> Fatal error: Use of unimplemented initializer 'init(nibName:bundle:)' for class 'appName.NavigationViewController

Adding the following initializer fixes the issue

```swift
override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
    super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
}
```

Can anyone point out why this above initializer is not required in iOS 13 but is needed in iOS 12?

Comment: Seems like a bug to me. This can cause issues, I am unable to create a custom init with a variable that's non-optional because now I have to implement nibNameOrNil:nibBundleOrNil: which leads to error like: 
Property 'self.myCustomInitProperty' not initialized at super.init call